# How to get this into code form (if statement)

Tags: ios, xcode, url, uiwebview

How to make this statement into an actual "if statement" in Xcode?

This is what i want in the form of an "if statement" :

"if a certain link is shown in UIWebView, then image.hidden = NO;"

The UIWebView is currently showing another website, but it has a page in that website that is the certain link I mentioned in the if statement.

The code for the UIWebView is this:

```
.h:
IBOutlet UIWebView *Name;
NSURL *NameURL;

.m

NameURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mywebname.com"];
NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: NameURL];
[Name loadRequest: Request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Anh Do's answer `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` isn't reliable for me.
Instead you should use:

```
currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

So the code will be like….

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSLog(@"HELLO DID GET CALLELDLLL LL LL LL ");

    //get the url you webView called "Name" is displaying...
    NSString *currentURL = Name.request.URL.absoluteString;
    //Check if that url is "mywebname.com"
    if ([currentURL isEqualToString:@"mywebname.com"])
    {
         image.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

**PS. Don't for get to add delegate to you `webview`**

By setting delegate do this..

In `ViewDidLoad`:

```
[Name setDelegate:self];
```

In .h file

```
@interface "nameofyourviewcontroller" : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I get this error at the if statement part of your code: local declaration of currentURL hides instance variable

Comment: Are you having the same object called `currentURL`? If so change my code `currentURL` to something else… `currentWebURL` perhaps?

Comment: Do you want me to replace my code up there to yours?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it by removing NSURL *NameURL in .h and implementing it in .m . I'm going to test it.

Comment: It didn't work. The image didn't show up when I tested it. Could it be because of the -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.

Comment: use nsLog and see if the method even get called. Did you set the delegate?

Comment: @ Ty Tan Lee Could you please give me an example of the NSLog. I did set the delegate to webView

Comment: @ Ty Tan Lee IT WORKED THANKS SO MUCH. I forgot to set the delegate in my .h file.

Answer (score 1):

To access the actual page content within UIWebView, you need to use 
`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to invoke some JavaScript snippet. Once the page finishes loading, the idea is to loop through all `a` elements and check for its `href` attribute, comparing it to the 'certain site' that you mentioned.

Rough implementation:

#### JS Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++)
{
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href.match(/google/) return 'YES';
}
return 'NO';
```

#### Obj-C Code

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  NSString *test = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:aboveJSString];
  if ([test isEqualToString:@"YES"]) image.hidden = NO;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I put the JS Code where it says aboveJSString in Obj-C Code?